# Python Curses for windows not overwriting strings

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I'm using the package from: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses
and I'm making a screen object like so:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import curses
import time

class Screen(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.noecho()
        self.stdscr.keypad(1)
        curses.curs_set(0)

        Y, X = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()

        gap = 1
        self.bar = self.stdscr.derwin(3, X, 1, 0)
        self.threads = self.stdscr.derwin(Y-4-gap, X/2, 4, 0)
        self.messages = self.stdscr.derwin(Y-4-gap, X/2 -1, 4, X/2 + 1)

        # self.bar.box()
        # self.threads.box()
        # self.messages.box()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

    def refresh(self):
        self.bar.refresh()
        self.threads.refresh()
        self.messages.refresh()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Screen() as S:
        S.bar.addstr(0, 0, "Hello")
        S.refresh()
        time.sleep(2)
        S.bar.addstr(0, 0, "\rHi")
        time.sleep(2)
```

But when I actually execute this it just stays as "Hello" rather than overwriting it and printing "hi"

I've tried removing the '\r' but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clean the "Hello", you can add `S.bar.erase()` before `S.bar.addstr(0, 0, "\rHi")`. And you also need to add `S.refresh()` after `S.bar.addstr(0, 0, "\rHi")` to update the window, or the "Hi" will not be displayed.

The `window.erase()` is used to clear the window. You can check the documentation for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html